# Leasing terminology in the USA: What is the difference between "Lease Contract" and "Contemplated Lease Contract"?

Tags: contract-law, rental-property

A question on the leasing terminology in the USA:

What is the difference between "Lease Contract" and "Contemplated Lease Contract"?

Answer (score 1):

Based on simple English, a "Lease Contract" is what you have between a lessor and lessee. A "Contemplated Lease Contract" is what you have when you are thinking about forming a "Lease Contract".

Comment: In other words, before the lease contract is signed, it isn't yet a lease contract, so should be modified with some other word like "proposed" or "prospective" or indeed "contemplated," correct?

Comment: Right.  A contract is a meeting of mind and an exchange of values.  When no values have been exchanged and the minds haven't met yet, but one "mind" has been written on paper, that's a "contemplated contract".